# Java string.matches() returns wrong statement

Tags: java, regex, string

I'm running some code through the eclipse debugger and `a[1].matches("[a-zA-Z]")` is not equating to `true` when `a[1] = "ABCD"` (`a` is a string array).

I've read the javadoc on `matches` and `[a-zA-Z]` should be a valid regular expression..

Anyone know where I'm going wrong?

Comment: `[a-zA-Z]` means match any SINGLE character in that range. You need to add a qualifier afterwards, such as `*` (0 or more) or `+` (1 or more).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try using this expression: `[a-zA-Z]*` (will match zero or more characters).

If you require at least one character, use: `[a-zA-Z]+`

The expression you're using will only match a single alpha character since it's not [quantified](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/regex/quant.html).

Comment: this will also yield true for `a[1] == ""` [which might or might not be what the OP wants, you can't tell from the question].

Comment: @amit - I've updated my answer to include a couple of examples.

Answer (score 2):

Try `a[1].matches("[a-zA-Z]+")`. It says "one or more characters" must match instead of only a single character.

Note that '*' instead of '+' matches "zero or more characters' so it will match empty String (probably not what you want).

Answer (score 1):

I think it should be `a[1].matches("[a-zA-Z]*")`

Answer (score 0):

`[a-zA-Z]` would only accept a single letter. You probably need `[a-zA-Z]*`.

Answer (score 0):

The reason that you're not matching that is string is that your RegEx expression is trying to match just a single character. Try this:

```
a[1].matches("[a-zA-Z]*")
```

Answer (score 0):

```
a[1].matches("[a-zA-Z\\s]+")
```

may help

Answer (score 0):

This expression should work for checking whether a string contains all alphabet or not.

```
a[1].matches("^[a-zA-Z]*$")
```